# Unity RaycastHit2D sprites error C#. Figured out that this code only works on 3D colliders so how do I change it so that I can use it on 2D colliders?

Tags: c#, 2d

Figured out that this code only works on 3D colliders so how do I change it so that I can use it on 2D colliders?

Below is the c# code.

using UnityEngine;

// This script allows you to drag this GameObject using any finger, as long it has a collider
public class SimpleDrag : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This stores the layers we want the raycast to hit (make sure this GameObject's layer is included!)
    public LayerMask LayerMask = UnityEngine.Physics.DefaultRaycastLayers;

```
// This stores the finger that's currently dragging this GameObject
private Lean.LeanFinger draggingFinger;

protected virtual void OnEnable()
{
    // Hook into the OnFingerDown event
    Lean.LeanTouch.OnFingerDown += OnFingerDown;

    // Hook into the OnFingerUp event
    Lean.LeanTouch.OnFingerUp += OnFingerUp;
}

protected virtual void OnDisable()
{
    // Unhook the OnFingerDown event
    Lean.LeanTouch.OnFingerDown -= OnFingerDown;

    // Unhook the OnFingerUp event
    Lean.LeanTouch.OnFingerUp -= OnFingerUp;
}

protected virtual void LateUpdate()
{
    // If there is an active finger, move this GameObject based on it
    if (draggingFinger != null)
    {
        Lean.LeanTouch.MoveObject(transform, draggingFinger.DeltaScreenPosition);
    }
}

public void OnFingerDown(Lean.LeanFinger finger)
{
    // Raycast information
    var ray = finger.GetRay();
    var hit = default(RaycastHit);

    // Was this finger pressed down on a collider?
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, float.PositiveInfinity, LayerMask) == true)
    {
        // Was that collider this one?
        if (hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject)
        {
            // Set the current finger to this one
            draggingFinger = finger;
        }
    }
}

public void OnFingerUp(Lean.LeanFinger finger)
{
    // Was the current finger lifted from the screen?
    if (finger == draggingFinger)
    {
        // Unset the current finger
        draggingFinger = null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `Physics` class is for 3D (as you guessed) so what you need to do is change your code to use the 2D Physics. Aka [`Physics2D`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html), this will collide with 2D colliers. So for the OnFingerDown method you'll need to change the physics call:

```
public void OnFingerDown(Lean.LeanFinger finger)
{
    // Raycast information
    var ray = finger.GetRay();
    var hit = default(RaycastHit2D);

    // Was this finger pressed down on a collider?
    if (Physics2D.Raycast(ray, out hit, float.PositiveInfinity, LayerMask))
    {
        // Was that collider this one?
        if (hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject)
        {
            // Set the current finger to this one
            draggingFinger = finger;
        }
    }
}
```

That should work with 2D colliders:)

Side note, when you have somthing that returns a bool and your using things that evaluate true or false to work you don't need to have them work it out again. For the raycast it returns true/false already so there is no need to check if it's true. The more you know....